# SectionIndexer with AlphabetIndexer stuck at K

Tags: android

My listfragment has a custom `CursorAdapter` that implements the `SectionIndexer`. I use the `AlphabetIndexer` helper class to implement the `SectionIndexer` in a simple standard way. But for some reason, while scrolling, the character in the scroll changes from K to R, skipping all the letters in between. So even though there are dozens of entries starting with L,M,N,O,P,Q, they all are coming under the section K. If i remove the K from the alphabet parameter of the AlphabetIndexer, the same behaviour persist with L. Any idea why this could happen?

```
private class ContactsAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer {
private AlphabetIndexer mAlphabetIndexer; // Stores the AlphabetIndexer instance
...
public ContactsAdapter(Context context) {
...
final String alphabet = context.getString(R.string.alphabet); // alphabet=" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
mAlphabetIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(null, ContactsQuery.SORT_KEY, alphabet);

/**
         * An override of getCount that simplifies accessing the Cursor. If the Cursor is null,
         * getCount returns zero. As a result, no test for Cursor == null is needed.
         */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (getCursor() == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return super.getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
            // Update the AlphabetIndexer with new cursor as well
            mAlphabetIndexer.setCursor(newCursor);
            return super.swapCursor(newCursor);
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] getSections() {
            return mAlphabetIndexer.getSections();
        }

        /**
         * Defines the SectionIndexer.getPositionForSection() interface.
         */
        @Override
        public int getPositionForSection(int i) {
            if (getCursor() == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return mAlphabetIndexer.getPositionForSection(i);
        }

        /**
         * Defines the SectionIndexer.getSectionForPosition() interface.
         */
        @Override
        public int getSectionForPosition(int i) {
            if (getCursor() == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return mAlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(i);
        }


}

}
```

Comment: did you solve this? Please post the solution.